# TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) { app.handle(req, res, next); } has no method 'configure'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can anyone point out why am I getting this error when I am trying to run the following code ?

```
 var express = require('express');
 var login = require('./routes/login');

 var app = express();

 //all environments
 app.configure(function () {
 app.use(express.logger('dev')); 
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
});


app.post('/loginUser',login.loginUser);


app.listen(3000);

console.log("Listening on port 3000...");
```

I am using node.js with the express 4.x version.

Comment: express 4.x version is completely different from the older versions. So all posts about express will send you in the wrong direction. I would suggest that you stick with an older version for now. `npm install express@3.4.8`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Express 4.x does not have configure method.

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x

Also, it doesn't have `express.logger` and `express.bodyParser` had been deprecated ages ago.

Answer (score 10):

Tom in his blog post [new-features-node-express-4](http://blog.tompawlak.org/new-features-node-express-4) provides examples of how to convert from using app.configure in express version 3.x to removing it in express version 4.0.

For convenience I added the code example below.  In the examples below you can replace "set" with "use".

Version 3.x

```
// all environments
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('title', 'Application Title');
})

// development only
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.set('mongodb_uri', 'mongo://localhost/dev');
})

// production only
app.configure('production', function(){
  app.set('mongodb_uri', 'mongo://localhost/prod');
})
```

Version 4.0

```
// all environments
app.set('title', 'Application Title');

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.set('mongodb_uri', 'mongo://localhost/dev');
}

// production only
if ('production' == app.get('env')) {
  app.set('mongodb_uri', 'mongo://localhost/prod');
}
```